# How to enter message in serial communication using screen

Tags: usb, tty, serial-port, serial-console, ttyusb

I use `screen \dev\ttyUSB0` command to connect to virtual serial port. It prints out the incoming communication, but I dont know how to send message back to the connected device.

Thanks for answers

EDIT:

Turns out I send out character as I type, but I cannot see them. So is there any way I could see what am I typing before sending? Could it work something like terminal?

Comment: Have you tried typing?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happens. If there was way how to stop incoming message send my message and then resume id.

Comment: You should know what the attached device sends, and what it expects. There must be some documentation. What about consulting that instead of people who don't even know what device you're talking to?

Comment: It is likely that the device isn't echoing your input, so you need to type blindly. If you have any documentation about its communication protocol it might be easier to write some code in Python or some other language that you're familiar with, so you can filter the information printed to the console.

Comment: I am using SAMD21 based device I made myself currently it is sending only `A`. You were right I send out character as I type, but I cannot see them. So is there any way I could see what am I typing before sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type. Anything you type (that is not a `screen` escape key combination) will be sent to the device.

The problem might be that the device is not currently echoing back the characters you type, so it may look like you're not sending anything.

Using `screen` in the way you describe is pretty much a set of "straight pipes": from your keyboard to the device, and from the device to your screen. That's all. If you need to adjust the parameters of the serial communication, you should probably use `minicom` or some other program that is actually designed to work with hardware serial ports.

If the device cannot be configured to echo the input characters back at you (to conform to the Unix common serial port behavior), then you would need a communication program that has an option to activate "local echo". Minicom can do that with <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: So is there any way I could do local echo using screen? I really like the simplicity of the program. Maybe another session that would monitor outcoming communication?

Comment: Anyway, switched to minicom and everything works great. Thanks for help